# Javascript es2015 import syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm looking to import a portion of a package. I have this code:

```
import N, { Newsitem } from '../../newsitems/src/index'
class Home extends React.Component {
  render () {
    console.log('+++ N:', N )
    console.log('+++ Newsitem:', Newsitem)
    return (
      <div>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12}>
            <h1>Home...</h1>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <N.Newsitem />
      </div>)
  }
}
```

Gives me this log output:

```
+++ N: { Newsitem: [Function: Newsitem],
  Newsitems: [Function: Newsitems] }
+++ Newsitem: undefined
```

How would I import only a part of a package? I thought this syntax should work.

Comment: Please show us how you did export it.

Comment: Looks like you're default-exporting an object, instead of properly using named exports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly export rather than using default export only. 
Something like

```
export function Newsitem ...

export function Newsitems...
```

or

```
export {
  Newsitem,
  Newsitems
}
```

Comment: Somehow, the first syntax worked, and the second syntax didn't. But yeah that's right.

Comment: @VictorPiousbox The second should not have had a `default`…